# CSS Styling a definition list <dl>

Tags: css

I'm trying to CSS style some HTML to look like the following image. I've decided to use a definition list with some classes to do this.

[image]

I'm trying to

1. move the price to immediately follow the dt tag and
2. remove the default `dd` styling so that it is all the way to the left.

Here is my HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Classic Italian Hoagie</dt>
    <dd class="price">$8</dd>
    <dd class="desc">Pepperoni, salimi, capicola, banana peppers, romaine, tomatoes, provolone & housemade olive oil & herb vinaigrette on a hoagie bun</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried so far?

Comment: definition list is not a good option for this type of styling

Comment: @sandeep I think it's alright. What would you suggest as a replacement? Lots of messy `li`s with classes?

Comment: @JamWaffles; check my example with less css class & proper markup

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hLFL6/11/

Comment: @sandeep A `span` inside an `h3`, with a following `p`? I wouldn't call that proper markup. Tomalak appears to agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, floating the `dt` and the `.price` to the left will line them up next to one another.

You can then get the other `dd` tags to `clear:left` which solves your problem.

```
dt, .price{
    float:left;
    clear:none;
    margin-right:5px;
}

dd{
    clear:left;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/USLjN/)

As for your second question, I don't see any default styling causing margins on the `dd`. It looks as required for me but if not you can always put a `margin-left:0;` on the `dd`.